# R: dbGetQuery function with a where statement that takes an Excel list (column)

Tags: sql, r

I'm new to R. I have a database and I need to pull a column from a separate excel file. So let me try through using the code:

```
myquery = dbGetQuery(
 theconnection, 
 "select var1, var2, var3
 from table1
 where var2 = 9999999
 commit;" )
```

This is the code which selects if variable2 is 9999999. What I want to do, however, is "where var2 IN ("file path.xlsx"). It would look something like this:

```
myquery = dbGetQuery(
 theconnection, 
 "select var1, var2, var3
 from table1
 where var2 IN ("file path.xlsx")
 commit;" )
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of database do you use? In most DBs, you could create a temporary table with the xl file

Comment: @Waldi: It's relational. The Excel file is basically a list of 8,000+ IDs. I thought I could maybe read the excel file as a df, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the DB system is doing the join on the server, not on your client where the df is. Hence my suggestion to create a temporary table on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumption that you cannot upload data to do things *efficiently*, here are two options that are notably less efficient.

1. If you have a "reasonable" number of possible values, then you can include them in the query directly. Regardless of how to read in the xlsx file, I'll assume that you have a vector `var2candidates`, then use

   ```r
   var2candidates <- c(99999999, 999912, 123) # whatever you get from the xlsx file
   qry <- sprintf("select var1, var2, var3 from table1 where var2 in (%s)",
                  paste(rep("?", length(var2candidates)), collapse=","))
   # if the length is 3, then the query would look like this:
   # [1] "select var1, var2, var3 from table1 where var2 in (?,?,?)"
   myquery = dbGetQuery(theconnection, qry, params = var2candidates)
   ```

   When I say "reasonable", I don't know if `DBI::dbGetQuery` has a limit on bound parameters. If this is on the order of 50 or fewer, then this should work. If *much* more, then you might get an error with this ... I don't know for certain. (Quick testing on a sql server instance I have suggests that it accepts a length of 2097 but no more; this might apply to you as well. It might be a per-DBMS/instance setting as well. YMMV)
2. (Potentially much-less efficient due to downloading all data.) Query the data without the `var2` constraint and filter locally:

   ```r
   myquery = dbGetQuery(
    theconnection, 
    "select var1, var2, var3
    from table1
    commit;" )
   # subset myquery based on what you have in the xlsx file
   myquery[ myquery$var2 %in% var2candidates, ]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table in the database from the Excel file :

```
library(readxl)
xldata <- read_excel("file path.xlsx")

dbWriteTable(conn, 'xldata', xldata, temporary = TRUE)

myquery = dbGetQuery(
 conn, 
 "select var1, var2, var3
 from table1
 where var2 IN (select var2 from xldata)" )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the dbCreatTable statement. I basically need to figure out a way to do this within the function above.

Comment: @Waldi by the way, dbCreateTable statement creates an empty table. you need to use dbWriteTable after creating.

Comment: @Samet Sökel, thanks you're right. Actually this is what I was thinking about : use directly dbWriteTable, I mixed it up with dbCreateTable - corrected

Comment: well actually you don't mixed it up completely, they both required. without creating table `dbWriteTable` can not find the table to write.

Comment: @Samet, try  `con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:"); dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[1:5, ])`

Comment: big time ! I tried just before, yeah you are correct but in PostgreSQL databases I can't do without creating table. Probably because of differences between database drivers and their sytnaxes.

Comment: @Samet, yes this is tricky, this is why I asked the DB type. Another example is `temporary=TRUE` not working on SQL Server, just need to name the table with # prefix,  f.i. #TEMP

Comment: JohnD, what do you mean when you say *"don't have access to the dbCreatTable statement"*? Are you saying that you do not have permissions to create tables on the server? That is typically something you can work around using temporary tables, as Waldi suggested.

Comment: @r2evans: Yes, that's right. I was getting that error with the dbCreateTable. With dbWritetable I'm getting this error: Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) :  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1374: 00000: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SAP IQ]Syntax error near 'TABLE' on line 1:

dbWriteTable(myConnection,'TEMP', df2, temporary=T)

Comment: Okay, some DBMS's do not support the syntax `"create temporary table ..."`; while I thought it was just sql server, perhaps your instances does too. You have it tagged [tag:mysql] but the error suggests something else (I believe SAP IQ is sybase-based, which means I think it inherits more from sql server than mysql. If you do not know it is mysql, you should likely remove that tag, as it can be misleading.)

Comment: For instance, while `create temporary table data1 (...)` works on most DBMSes, sql server requires `create table #data1 (...)` (or `##data1` for a global-temporary table). It might work for you to instead use `dbWriteTable(myConnection, "#TEMP", df2)` to make it temporary. Note: `#TEMP` will be visible only to this one connection, not others even if you; `##TEMP` will be visible to all of *your* (same user-id) connections, nobody else; and the table disappears when *this* connection closes or is interrupted.

Comment: @r2evans: I've removed the tag. I'm getting the error "you don't have permission to use the "CREATE TABLE" statement.

Comment: I think that even with temporary tables, the DB administrator should decide whether you have or not the right to use this functionality

Comment: @Waldi and r2evans, Thanks for all your help with this. I think because it's sensitive there are some restrictions that I'll have to find a work around to.